# Is only the height of the spleen concerning?

Tags: immune-system

Say you have a spleen size of 12.2cm by 11.8cm by 6.2cm when it should be 11cm by 6.5cm by 5.5cm (correct me if I'm wrong on the norm!), is only the height i.e. 11cm or 12.2cm matter I stated above?

Comment: There are many causes of an enlarged spleen, but it's not clear what you're really asking here. Please clarify your question.

Comment: If the spleen is double average wide or thick, is that ok unless the height is? My question literally asks this. "Is only the spleen's height CONCERNING?"

Comment: I find the coherency of this question to be concerning.

Comment: No because I was told this by a semi nurse and google is like only showing the height of spleens, so, I don't know then if only the hieght matters and much longer widths/thicknesses on the other 2 axis are fine.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://www.ultrasoundpaedia.com/normal-spleen/), height is not the only criteria for determining if a spleen is enlarged.

[image]